# VBscript to pull users default printer

Tags: vbscript, registry

I have a situation with a vbscript that is bugging the holly hell out of me. I am writing a vbscript that pulls the default printer name for a user. The reason I need this is I am later removing all printers and then putting them back with a different driver (that code is working) and I want to put the users default printer back to the one that had it as.

Now below is my code the issue I am having is if I hard code the NetID everything works fine but if I do it dynamically as below I get an error. Not all machines have the same netID so that is why I need to do it dynamically. I just don't understand why I get an error with the code I have. The error message is "Invalid root in registry key".

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.echo WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\NetID")
Key = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\NetID") 
Test = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\" & Key & "\"
WScript.echo WshShell.RegRead(Test)
```

Example:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.echo WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\NetID")
Key = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\NetID") ' Returns 12345
Test = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\" & Key & "\"
WScript.echo WshShell.RegRead(Test) ' Error message

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.echo WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\NetID")
Key = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\NetID") ' Returns 12345
Test = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\12345\"
WScript.echo WshShell.RegRead(Test) 'Returns Default printer value of Lexmark T642
```

That is what I can't figure out. The key is there and has a value called (Default) set as the name of the default printer. I can hard code the script to get what I need but not every machine has the same NetID. I don't know why it works hard coded but not dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

That error message appear when the key you trying to read not exist.
For instance, running this code on my machine

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Key = WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Printers\DeviceOld")
WScript.Echo Key   ' -> "Foxit PDF Printer"

Test = "HKCU\Printers\" & Key & "\"

' ADD this line for debuging
WScript.Echo Test  ' -> "HKCU\Printers\Foxit PDF Printer\"

' but that key not exist, so...
Key = WshShell.RegRead(Test)  ' -> ...of couse error
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Panayot but I'm still confused. I have edited my question above to give an example of the issue.

Comment: Hmm, maybe removing the "\" at the end of the key path will help?